How to Send Newly Added Row to a Webhook in Google Sheets using Google Apps Script
There is a Google Sheet in which Meta leads coming, I want them to send to my CRM as it supports webhooks. So, I piece together a GAPPS script from various sources on the internet to do it but it is not firing when a new row is added from Meta connector.
But when I manually copy-paste the row at the end then it works. But I want to make it work automatically.....
function editRow(e){
  if(e.changeType=="EDIT" || e.changeType=="INSERT_ROW"){ 
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //get activated Spreadsheet
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); //get sheet by sheet name
    var headings = sheet.getDataRange().offset(0, 0, 1).getValues()[0]; //get heading
    
    var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
    var column = sheet.getActiveRange().getColumn();
    Logger.log("row: "+row+" column: "+column);
    
    var values = sheet.getSheetValues(
        row, // starting row
        1, // starting column
        1, // number of rows
        5 // number of columns
    );
    Logger.log(values);
    var payload ={}
    
    for (i = 0; i < headings.length; i++) {
      var name = headings[i];
      var value = values[0][i];
      payload[name] = value;
    }
    Logger.log(payload);
    var options = {
        'method': 'post',
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'payload': JSON.stringify(payload)
    };
    UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://webhook.site/XXXXXXX', options);
  }
}

Is it possible? If yes then please help me make it work or suggest an alternate way. Thanks.

That is to be expected. onEdit(e) only triggers when there is human intervention wherein a user edits the actual spreadsheet. If you want to automate your script, you might consider installing a time-based trigger so that your script will run periodically.
